# Não consigo importar o pacote Observable do recurso timer?

Tags: angular

Veja atentamente esse tutorial:

[Importing RXJS Observable functions in Angular 5](https://medium.com/code-divoire/importing-rxjs-observable-functions-in-angular-5-cca1f9bac108)

Estou com dificuldade para realizar a importação do Observable do recurso **timer**, já tentei escrever o caminho de várias maneiras e não consigo importar.

Observem como está o cabeçalho da minha classe!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tentei instalar  outras versões do **rxjs**

Eu tinha o `"rxjs": "5.1.0"`, mas depois eu tentei da versão `"rxjs": "^5.5.5"` e da versão  `"rxjs": "^6.2.2"`, e sem sucesso.

Preciso muito de ajuda

Comment: Na versao 6+ seria import { timer } from 'rxjs';

Comment: Desculpe, mas não entendi o que disse.

Comment: Na versao do rxjs 6 ou maior seria  assim:  import { timer } from 'rxjs';

Comment: @EduardoVargas desculpe, porém sua sugestão não pegou.

Comment: Deleta o node modules e instala tudo dnv. Tenha certeza que vc esta usando o 6. Pode ser que seu projeto não esteja configurado corretamente tbm. Vc usou o angular cli para gerar ele?

Comment: Seus outros imports tbm estão estranhos era pra ser @angular/animations e não ter o node_modules por exemplo. Você esta usando um pathing absoluto invés de relativo.

Comment: Acabei de resolver, instalei a versão `"rxjs": "5.1.0"` e coloquei esse caminho `import { Observable } from '../../../../node_modules/rxjs/rx';` e funcionou.

Comment: Estranho ter o node_modules em seus imports...

Comment: Muito estranho. Já pensou em usar só `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/rx;` ? Não estraga nada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer';

```
const timer = Observable.timer(1, 1000);
    this.sub = timer.subscribe(
      t => console.log(`passou 1 segundo));
```